# How to automatically add custom user properties to all new reply in Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing Outlook VSTO add-in where we assign custom user properties call "Ownership" to all new emails. The code I use is below.

```
string UserName = (string)application.ActiveExplorer().Session.CurrentUser.Name;

MailUserProperties = SelectedMail.UserProperties;
                MailUserProperty = MailUserProperties.Add("Ownership", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText, true, 1);
                MailUserProperty.Value = UserName;
                SelectedMail.Save();
```

Is it possible that when someone replies to us, Outlook would automatically pick up "Ownership" properties value from original email and assign to all incoming replies?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the [Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reply(even)) event of the `MailItem` class where you may set all the required user properties.

There is no automatic way for doing so in Outlook. You must handle such scenarios in the code. The [MailItem.GetConversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation) method allows obtaining a [Conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.conversation) object that represents the conversation to which this item belongs.

`GetConversation` returns Null (Nothing in Visual Basic) if no conversation exists for the item. No conversation exists for an item in the following scenarios:

- The item has not been saved. An item can be saved programmatically, by user action, or by auto-save.
- For an item that can be sent (for example, a mail item, appointment item, or contact item), the item has not been sent.
- Conversations have been disabled through the Windows registry.
- The store does not support Conversation view (for example, Outlook is running in classic online mode against a version of Microsoft Exchange earlier than Microsoft Exchange Server 2010). Use the `IsConversationEnabled` property of the Store object to determine whether the store supports `Conversation` view.